# Where can I find a SQLite code editor with schema intellisense?

Tags: sqlite, intellisense

Is there a SQL editor that supports SQLite databases and also features schema intellisense?

I can't seem to find anything out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [SQLite Administrator](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/)? It's not bad at all and it's free :).

Comment: I like it.  The downside: has no preferences screen.  How does one tell it to have the intellisense come up automatically instead of having to press Ctrl+Space

Answer (score 0):

You should try [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/). They have a [SQLite SQL Editor](http://www.razorsql.com/features/sqlite_editor.html).

From their page:

- SQL syntax highlighting
- SQL function lookup
- Auto table lookup and completion
- Auto column lookup and completion
- Extensive find, replace, and find / replace in files functionality
- Bracket, parenthesis, and brace auto matching
- Support for parameterized queries
- SQL Formatter
- Execute, Execute Fetch All, and Execute Batch functions
- Multi-Tabular Display of Query Results
- Sortable Query Results
- Filterable Query Results
- Searchable Query Results
- SQL History for All Queries, and Query Logging Per Connection
- Query navigator for displaying a clickable display of queries in the editor
- Key Ahead functionality for one-click population of user-defined text
- Built-in and Custom User Templates
- Connection Keep-Alive
- Plugin API (Allows users to add custom functionality to RazorSQL)

Comment: Has a bit of a redrawing problem on Windows 2000, but on the whole probably the best of the bunch.